# kafka consumer group expired?

Tags: go, apache-kafka

Immediately after I commitoffset using the golang client.  https://github.com/Shopify/sarama

```
./kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper=localhost:2181 --topic=my-replicated-topic --group=ib --broker-info 

Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner

ib              my-replicated-topic            0   12              12              0               none

BROKER INFO

1 -> localhost:9093
```

However, after several minute, I run the same checker command.

```
./kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper=localhost:2181 --topic=my-replicated-topic --group=ib --broker-info 


Exiting due to: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/ib/offsets/my-replicated-topic/0.
```

And I check the zookeeper, the node never exists at any time, even when checker list the offset correctly.

sarama commit: 23d523386ce0c886e56c9faf1b9c78b07e5b8c90
kafka 0.8.2.1
golang 1.3

kafka server config:

```
broker.id=1
port=9093
num.network.threads=3
 num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.cleaner.enable=false
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

It seems to me that the consumer group get expired. How can I make the consumer group persist?

Comment: owner "none" seems incorrect - can you tell us more about your OS and how you created the topic? i suspect this problem is more about the setup of the system environment than it is about your use of Sarama.

Comment: @snwight   I create the topic with the line in [link](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction)  `bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic`     My os is ubuntu 12.04.  It bothers me that I find no api to  create the consumer group explicitly, instead I create it implicitly by  putting it in the commitoffset api call.

Comment: How do you start zookeeper?

How do you check that node exists?

Can you run bin/zkCli.sh and execute
ls /consumers/ib/offsets/my-replicated-topic/0

What is the output?

Comment: @kostya   I start zookeeper via `zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh start` node  /consumers/ib  never exists on both circumstances. How can I create it?

Answer (score 0):

Sarama does not talk to zookeeper, I should use high level consumer group library 
instead.

https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/issues/452